# Python TypeError: '_asyncio.Future' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-requests, python-asyncio

Good afternoon! I am making a program that needs to POST 10,000 images to the API using the Python **requests** library. After sending every request, I receive a response with a hash(IpfsHash), which I need to write into a dictionary of the form: **"Hash": "Number"**. To get started, I created a simple code (using a loop and not using async) and it worked. And then I used async to speed things up.
Here is the code:

```
import asyncio
import requests

jsonHashes = {}
responses = []

def pinToIPFS(number):
    url = 'https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinFileToIPFS'
    par = {
        'pinata_api_key': 'blabla',
        'pinata_secret_api_key': 'blabla'
    }
    file = {'file': open(str(number) + '.jpg', 'rb')}

    res = requests.post(url, headers = par, files = file)
    jsonHashes[res.json()['IpfsHash']] = number
    print(res.json()['IpfsHash'] + ' = ' + str(number))


async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    futures = []
    for i in range(2):
        futures = loop.run_in_executor(None, pinToIPFS, i)
    for i in range(2):
        jsonHashes[await futures[i].json()['IpfsHash']] = i
    

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())


print(jsonHashes)
```

But, for some reason I get the error:

`TypeError: '_asyncio.Future' object is not subscriptable`

And immediately after that, I get a response to the requests:

```
QmcZR3cpeVzQ56gyWs83dRS51rtkqjyoF167paJMPrn32w = 1
QmehUERFcR6Erha6RtScDwfm1ACpZgGPrd5NNVnYWeDoH4 = 0
```

P.S. For simplicity, I put 2 iterations instead of 10,000.

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: @MichaelButscher
Thanks for the answer, but I just realized that I have an error on the line:
`futures = loop.run_in_executor(None, pinToIPFS, i)`
It must be:
`futures.append(loop.run_in_executor(None, pinToIPFS, i))`
But I still get the error:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'json'`
Because python writes the result of the function execution before it receives a response from the server. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Why use asyncio if you’re going to use requests and run everything in threads? Why not use an asyncio-aware http library?

Comment: Better create a new question with the modified code and the full traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic part is here:

```py
    for i in range(2):
        futures = loop.run_in_executor(None, pinToIPFS, i)
    for i in range(2):
        jsonHashes[await futures[i].json()['IpfsHash']] = i
```

[`loop.run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) returns ***one*** `asyncio.Future` object, not a list of them. I do not have an idea how to rewrite your code to make it work - firstly, I'm not familiar with `asyncio`, but mainly, because I see no need for that second for loop at all.

Comment: Oh yes, I was wrong. Thanks. I replaced this line with: `futures.append(loop.run_in_executor(None, pinToIPFS, i))`
 And now I get the error: 
`AttributeError: '_asyncio.Future' object has no attribute 'json'`
 Also I changed the line in the second loop to:
`jsonHashes[(await futures[i]).json()['IpfsHash']] = i`
And now I got the error:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'json'`
I think this is because the code asks for the json attribute before it receives a response from the server. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @maxet24 no, sorry, as I said, I am not familiar with `asyncio`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate the code this way in order really await for the result:

```
f = await futures[i]
json = f.json()['IpfsHash']
jsonHashes[json]
```

Comment: @maxet24, just this answer. I had a similar error days ago.